# binary-search in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, binary-search

could someone tell me where is the mistake here?

```
let a = [|2;4;6;9;12|];;

a.(0);;
a.(4);;
a.(5);;

let binary_search array size x = 
  let n = size-1 in
  let p = ref 0 in
  let r = ref n in
  while (!p <= !r) do
    let q = (!p + !r)/2;          
    if array.(q) = x
    then raise ((Found_It (q));)                     
    else if (array.(q) <> x) && (array.(q) > x) 
    then (r := q - 1;)            
    else if array.(q) < x 
    then (p := q + 1;)
  done;
  else -1;;

exception Found_It of int;;
```

and if you have any suggestions about the binary-search in ocaml please inform me ?

Comment: What does this have to do with ***Emacs***? If the answer is, as it seems, *nothing*, then consider removing tag `emacs` and "emacs" from the title.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using an exception before it has been defined in the first place. Move the `exception Found_It ...` line above the `let binary_search ...` line.

Also, as Drew said, your problem has absolutely nothing to do with Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

exception Found_It of int;;          (* Here we declare an "exception". This is a special tool that will allow us to break loops. *)
                                     (* This particular exception takes an integer as an argument. *)

let binary_search array size x = 
  let n = size-1 in                   (* let the immutable variable n store the final index of the array *) 
  let p = ref 0 in                    (* let the minpoint q equals  0 *) 
  let r = ref n in                    (* let the maxpoint r equals n *)

```
while !p <= !r do     
  let q = ref ((!p + !r)/2) in              (* calculate the midpoint for roughly equal partition *) 
  print_int !q; print_string " "; 
  if array.(!q) = x                (* if x is found at index p *) 
  then raise (Found_It (!q))       (* then break the loop with Found_It, which "carries" the value of q  with it *)           
  else if array.(!q) > x         (* otherwise if q <> x and q > x *)
  then r := !q - 1                 (*change r index to search lower subarray*)
  else p := !q + 1                 (* otherwise if q < x change p index to search upper lower subarra *)
done;                             (* that's the end of the loop                                                *)
-1; 

                       (* so if we reach the end of the loop, output -1 for "Not found"             *)
```

with Found_It(x) -> x;;             (* if we broke the loop with q, output q                                     *)